# Determining Electric Potential due to a line of nonuniform charge density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential

> A rod of length $L$ lies along the x axis with its left end at the origin.
>   It has a non uniform charge density $\lambda = \alpha x$ where $\alpha$ is a positive constant.
>   Calculate the electric potential at $A(-d,0,0)$.

**First Attempt**

$$V =  - \int \vec{E}\cdot \mathrm d\vec{l}$$

Calculating The electric field $E$:

$$E = \int \frac{\lambda\,\mathrm dl}{4\pi \epsilon r^2 }$$

with $r^2 = (x+d)^2$

We then get 
$$E=\frac{\alpha}{4 \pi \epsilon}\Big(\ln(x+d) + \frac{d}{x+d}\Big)$$

Then,
$$V =  - \int_0^L E\cdot\mathrm dl= -(L+2d)\ln(l+d)+l+2d\ln(d)$$

**Second Attempt**

Using the formula 
$$V = \int_0^L \frac{\lambda\,\mathrm dl}{4\pi \epsilon r}$$

Evaluating this integral leads to the following :

$$V=\frac{\alpha}{4 \pi \epsilon}\Bigg(L-d \ln\Big(\frac{L+d}{d}\Big)\Bigg)$$

Why do both attempts give different solutions?

Comment: There are many issues here. In the first method you shouldn't have $r^2=(x+d)^2$. If you wan to go the first attempt route, you are trying to find the potential difference between the point A and the left end of the rod. So you need to find the field at all points on the line from $x=0$ to $x=-d$ (so maybe say $r^2=(x+x')^2$ and do the first integral over $x$?), and then do the line integral over $x'$ from $x=0$ to $x=-d$

Comment: Another issue is that the first method puts $V=0$ at $x=0$, but the second method puts $V=0$ at infinity. I would just stick with the second method.